# Java parse string with quotes

Tags: java, android, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string but I'm not sure how to parse it because its not a simple comma parse or something like that. The string i have is similar to this:

```
String s = "[\"142.5,106.1\",\"142.5,112.1\",\"143.5,119.1\",\"144.5,128.1\",\"146.5,138.1\",\"147.5,148.1\"]";
```

the string is coming from a jsonarray so that why the format is what it is, but my goal is parse this to a list. So the 142.5,106.1 is the x,y coordinates of one point and so on and so on. Anyone point me in the right direction for this? Thanks.

Comment: This does not seem to be like a string do you mean the String is something like `"[\"142.5,106.1\"...` if we try to initialize it.

Comment: Sorry for off-topic. Is it possible for you to use scala in your project? Here is a parser: http://pastebin.com/utAVRLyD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a StringTokenizer("\"[,]") and then read two values at a time (x, y, x, y, etc.).

Comment: Agreed. Optimally you would use GSON to automatically create an array or List, but if all you have is a String, StringTokenizer or String.split works well.

Comment: Yes, you're right Chuck, gson is very good and very simple to use (not the spirit of most java libs). But as the problem seemed to be very simple I thought it wasn't needed here. Of course, bflosabre, if you have more json to parse you should consider google gson.

Comment: this is way i ended up going with because it was the easiest to implement without having to make changes in the WCF, which is where this string is from. I know its not the ideal way but it works for now. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you well, but I think that what you miss is just specials characters escaping. With you internal double quotes use backslash like this \".

Comment: Well if this is not your problem, than  your String ("["142.5,106.1","142.5,112.1","143.5,119.1","144.5,128.1","146.5,138.1","147.5,148.1"]") is rubbbish. Either you copied it with a mistake or you should get a compile error with this. So don't really know why the downvote

Comment: I think this should be in the comment, as this is not an answer. Probably thats the reason for a down vote

Comment: Yeah, but I thought that is why he has a problem. Because you can't parse a broken String for sure;) But yeah, anyway... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with, if you can clean up the brackets it should make this quicker.  Probably better and other ways to do it, but I use split to seperate all commas.  so the List contains them in order ie list.get[0] and list.get[1] are a pair, etc.

public static void main(String[] args){

```
    String s ="[\"142.5,106.1\",\"142.5,112.1\",\"143.5,119.1\",\"144.5,128.1\",\"146.5,138.1\",\"147.5,148.1\"]";
    String[] set= s.split(",");
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for(int i=0; i<set.length;i++){
        System.out.println(set[i]);
        list.add(Double.parseDouble(set[i].replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll("\\]", "")));

    }
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is totally not what you are asking about, but I would like to discuss on the correct approach in your task not answer the question you post right away.

If you receive a json array of pairs, we can assume its serialized version will be like that (I am speculating here, because I am quite definite the string does not look like the one you share):

```
 "[[123, 234], [234, 456],...]"
```

If you use the so famous [Gson library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for parsing this string into java object you can do it as simple as that:

```
    String json = "[[123.3, 234.5], [234.1, 456.5]]";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    double [][] points = gson.fromJson(json, double[][].class);
    System.out.println(points[1][1]);
```

This outputs: `456.5` just as expected and you do not need to deal with parsing the json yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If its always in the same format the you can convert it like this.

```
 String s ="[\"142.5,106.1\",\"142.5,112.1\"]";

            s=s.replace("[", "");
            s=s.replace("]", "");

            String[] ss=s.split("\"");
        List list=   Arrays.asList(ss);

list.get(0);=142.5,106.1 // so on .....
```

As i understand what you required.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but low efficient solution will be using String methods like this:

```
    //(being s your example's String)
    String[] coordinates = s.substring(2, s.length() - 2).split("\",\"");
    //the two at the beginning and end of the substring is to eliminate braces ([]) and the first and last quotes (")
```

the coordinates String array will contain data like 120.1,140.4 etc.